# This operation is not supported for a relative URI PowerShell Azure

Tags: azure, azure-powershell

I am trying to create a URL in my $osDiskUri variable which will be used in below powershell command. But i get error "This operation is not supported for a relative URI"

```
$SourceMachineName = 'NewSource'
$DestinationBlobStorageURL = 'https://myblobstorage.blob.core.windows.net/vhds/'

$osDiskUri = '{0}{1}Fix.vhd' -f $DestinationBlobStorageURL, $SourceMachineName

Set-AzureRmVMOSDisk -VM $vmConfig -Name "myOsDisk" -VhdUri $osDiskUri -CreateOption Attach -Windows
```

But if I try to pass the hardcoded path in `$osDiskUri` for e.g. https://myblobstorage.blob.core.windows.net/vhds/OM-SourceFix.vhd

it works fine

Comment: I can able to work this from my side. Could you try to print the `$osDickUri` i.e, `Write-Output $osDiskUri` Also try to change like this `$osDiskUri = '{0}{1}Fix.vhd' -f $DestinationBlobStorageURL.ToString(), $SourceMachineName.ToString()`

Comment: If you have some update for your issue?

Answer (score 0):

I did the test without getting the error and it works well. The result below:

[image]

So, you can check your storage account and script again.